# Like '%' in where clause : is it always ignored

Tags: sql

To simplify/generalize my SQL, i want to use this code:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ColumnName LIKE '[To_be_replaced]'
```

If a certain field of my gui is empty, i want to replace "To_be_replaced" by "%":

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%'
```

but if it contains something, [To_be_replaced]" is replaced with the content, like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ColumnName LIKE 'foo'
```

My question is: do all (or major) SQL Engine optimize this code by simply ignoring where condition when content of like is "%" alone ?

Comment: I can't speak for all DBMS engines, but based on the (very limited test) query plans, SQL Server appears to ignore this condition.

Comment: What is your purpose

Comment: A question about "all SQL engines" is too broad.

Comment: If you're asking about all (or many) RDBMS tagging oracle only seems wrong.

Comment: I hoped one of the folks who deleted their answer would post a comment, but just in case: the usual way to construct queries dynamically is to omit the expression if it isn't meaningful. In this case, in your GUI, if the input field is empty, instead of adding `column LIKE '%s'`, you would simply omit this statement instead of relying on the engines to optimize it away. That being said, I still think it is an interesting question.

Comment: the answer for "all" engines is: check the execution plan. But the condition `where column LIKE '%'` can't  be "ignored" - it must be evaluated as `where column is not null`

Comment: The question should be: does the optimizer remove the condition if the column is defined as `NOT NULL`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I tested that too; even with a column defined as `not null`, the `like '%'` condition is still shown in the Explain Plan. So the answer for Oracle is that the condition is never optimized away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle does NOT ignore it. Indeed, Oracle is not SQL Standard compliant; to Oracle, a string of length zero is the same as NULL, and comparisons to NULL are never TRUE.

The Oracle optimizer (and the Oracle "logic", really, regardless of "optimizer") interprets `where str_column LIKE '%'` the same as `where str_column IS NOT NULL`. And, to judge by the EXPLAIN PLAN, it doesn't ignore the LIKE condition even then. The EXPLAIN PLAN shows an AND of two filters: `is not null` AND the `like '%'` condition, even though the latter should be omitted.

In any case, in Oracle omitting the LIKE condition altogether would produce different results (due to Oracle's non-standard treatment of empty strings).

**Added**:  Duh! In *any* DBMS a comparison to `NULL` never evaluates to TRUE, so `...like '%'` is equivalent to `is not null`. Even a horse knows that - even one with no name (see Comment below). I don't know what I was thinking.

Either way, the Oracle EXPLAIN PLAN shows the `is not null` condition and it STILL shows the `like '%'` condition as well. It is not optimized away.

Further: I created a table with a column declared specifically `not null`. The `like '%'` filter is still present in the EXPLAIN PLAN, even though now the `is not null` filter is no longer present (for obvious reasons).

Comment: The condition `where x LIKE '%'` **has** to be same as `where x is not null` for **all** DBMS. In this case this has absolutely nothing to do with Oracle's empty string handling

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Of course. I edited accordingly. Good catch, thank you!